# Accuracy of raycast on a moving object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I have a game a ball is bouncing. But everytime this ball is bouncing it varies that hit the point on the collider. So ray is not accurately check where it hit 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwph1.jpg)

```
 private void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position+ Vector3.down * 5, Color.red);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(hit.point, hit.point + Vector3.right * 5, Color.green);
            Debug.Log(hit.distance);


            if (hit.distance < .5f)
            {
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("top").GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("topup", true);

            }
            else {
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("top").GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("topup", false);

            }

        }
```

i have objects are 0.5f dia sphere and a box . maybe thaier size is so small that it cause this error to be easily seen?
code is like that

Comment: Can your provide enough code to recreate your issue, and possibly give an example of the issue?

Comment: yes i have added the code, anytime ball hits its not jumping from the same level with this code.. so `hit.point` not accurate

Comment: I don't see anything that would make it jump?  or are you using a physics material for that?

Comment: no i am using animation

Comment: Can you add your hierchy and maybe a screenshot of how you are doing the animation?

Comment: you can check this code with a ball and plane, just add this script into ball, you will see the error on bounce

Comment: if you are doing the bounce via animation then I won't see the same error, that is why I asked if you are using a physics material.

Comment: can you send me an example

Comment: because sometimes when update rerenders the screen, "hit.distance" changes varies so if i put <.5f it goes .34 and bounce,then sometimes sometimes go .45~ an bounce ..this generates an error looking. so it can be seen on the camera

Comment: @Eddge i have added https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwph1.jpg

Comment: https://we. tl/t-CKVA7QHAbL aded the project files